# How to add drop down in spring mvc form. I am getting an error "Unknown column 'domainOptions' in 'field list'"

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp

I am trying to populate drop down list using LinkedHashMap. When I tried to make an insert to the table, it throws an error "Unknown column 'domainOptions' in 'field list"

StatusUpdate.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="status")
public class StatusUpdate {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="status_id")
private int id;

@Column(name="project")
private String project;

@Column(name="domain")
private String Domain;

@Column(name="status")
private String status;

private LinkedHashMap<String, String> projectOptions;

private LinkedHashMap<String, String> domainOptions;

public StatusUpdate() {
    projectOptions= new LinkedHashMap();

    projectOptions.put("p1","project1");
    projectOptions.put("p2","project2");
    projectOptions.put("p3","project3");
    projectOptions.put("p4","project4");

    domainOptions= new LinkedHashMap();

    domainOptions.put("d1","domain1");
    domainOptions.put("d2","domain2");
    domainOptions.put("d3","domain3");
    domainOptions.put("d4","domain4");
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getProject() {
    return project;
}

public void setProject(String project) {
    this.project = project;
}

public String getDomain() {
    return Domain;
}

public void setDomain(String domain) {
    Domain = domain;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public LinkedHashMap<String, String> getProjectOptions() {
    return projectOptions;
}

public LinkedHashMap<String, String> getDomainOptions() {
    return domainOptions;
}

}
```

StatusUpdateDAOImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class StatusUpdateDAOImpl implements StatusUpdateDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public void saveStatus(StatusUpdate statusUpdate) {
    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    currentSession.saveOrUpdate(statusUpdate);

}}
```

status-update-form.jsp

```
<form:form action="saveStatus" modelAttribute="statusupdate" method="post">
            <p>
                <label style="padding-left:5.20%; padding-top:9.30%; color: #0091b0;font-size:20px">Domain:                    
                <form:select path="domain" >
                    <form:options items="${statusupdate.domainOptions}" style=" width:31.25%;height:10%;margin-top:1.16%"></form:options>
                </form:select>

               <label  style="padding-left:5.20%; padding-top:9.30%; color: #0091b0;font-size:20px">Domain:                    
                <form:select path="project" >
                    <form:options items="${statusupdate.projectOptions}" style=" width:31.25%;height:10%;margin-top:1.16%"></form:options>
                </form:select>
            </p>

            <p>
                <form:textarea path="status" rows="8" style="margin-top:4.65%;margin-left:5.63%;margin-right:5.63%; font-size:20px; padding-left:0px" placeholder="Update your status here..."></form:textarea>
            </p>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" name="update" class="button" value="UPDATE" style="font-size: 20px; margin-top:0.26%; margin-left:45.04%; width:16.90%; border-radius: 25px;"></input>
            </p>
        </form:form>
```

Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping("/saveStatus")
public String saveStatus(@ModelAttribute("statusupdate") StatusUpdate statusUpdate) {
    statusUpdateService.saveStatus(statusUpdate);
    return "redirect:/status-update-form";
}
```

I have searched for this on the web. But none of the sites explained involving hibernate. Please let me know how to resolve this? Thanks in advance

This is my table structure:

[image: This is my table structure:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by making the following changes in StatusUpdate.java

```
@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
private LinkedHashMap<String, String> projectOptions;

@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
private LinkedHashMap<String, String> domainOptions;
```